# SSIS Script Task Error - The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssis

I'm having a problem with NT Authority\Network Service not having sufficient permissions for executing some code in my SSIS Control flow VB.net script task.  It executes perfectly within debug, but when I create a Job Agent to execute it, I receive the following error concerning the permissions for Network Service:

```
10/23/2015 15:36:59,Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions,Error,1,DILBERT,Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions,Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions,,Executed as user: TAYLORS\DILBERT$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:36:59 PM  Error: 2015-10-23 15:37:03.37     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Generate and Save Reports      Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation.     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecution2005Impl.LoadReport(String Report<c/> String HistoryID<c/> ExecutionInfo2& executionInfo)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String Report<c/> String HistoryID<c/> ExecutionInfo& executionInfo)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message<c/> WebResponse response<c/> Stream responseStream<c/> Boolean asyncCall)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName<c/> Object[] parameters)     at ST_0378b6554b714d23a0b9474d41ce618e.vbproj.ReportServer.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String Report<c/> String HistoryID)     at ST_0378b6554b714d23a0b9474d41ce618e.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target<c/> Object[] arguments<c/> SignatureStruct& sig<c/> MethodAttributes methodAttributes<c/> RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj<c/> BindingFlags invokeAttr<c/> Binder binder<c/> Object[] parameters<c/> CultureInfo culture<c/> Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj<c/> BindingFlags invokeAttr<c/> Binder binder<c/> Object[] parameters<c/> CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name<c/> BindingFlags bindingFlags<c/> Binder binder<c/> Object target<c/> Object[] providedArgs<c/> ParameterModifier[] modifiers<c/> CultureInfo culture<c/> String[] namedParams)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:36:59 PM  Finished: 3:37:03 PM  Elapsed:  4.29 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:04,0,0,,,,0
10/23/2015 15:36:00,Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions,Error,0,DILBERT,Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User TAYLORS\administrator.  The last step to run was step 1 (Guest Satisfaction Subscriptions).,00:00:05,0,0,,,,0
```

I've looked at multiple websites, and I've found the following discussed for NT Authority\Network Service, so I verified what I found on our system:

1. On the Reporting Services Configuration Manager - The service account is set to "Network Service"
2. Report Server Database Credentials (ReportServer DB) - NT Authority\Network Service is granted db_owner and RSExecRole
3. URL Site Settings - NT Authority\Network Service granted System Administrator and System User (by me to ensure that isn't the problem)
4. SQL Server Credentials (User Mappings) - NT Authority\Network Service is granted db_owner, public, RSExecRole for ReportServer Database

A snippet of the code that is attempting to run:

```
objParams(0) = objParamSelect
objParams(1) = objParamUnitID

'Define everything to run the SSRS report on the report server
With objRSExec
    .Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    .Url = "http://<<Server>>/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx"
    .LoadReport("/<<Report Name>>", Nothing)
    .SetExecutionParameters(objParams, "en-us")
    objResult = .Render(strFileType, Nothing, strFileExtension, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
End With

objStream = File.Create(strFullPathName, objResult.Length)
With objStream
    .Write(objResult, 0, objResult.Length)
    .Close()
End With
```

With the above code, I'm attempting to execute an SSRS report by calling our report server URL.  The code seems to work well in debug mode, but I'm missing some permissions when executing from a Job Agent.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else is having this same problem, I wanted to post the answer to my own question.  Even though I provided the "Home" folder on the ReportingServices website with complete control, it didn't trickle down into the individual folder containing the SSRS report.  When I added "Network Service" to "Security" in that folder and provided it with simple "Browser" permissions, that fixed that error.